# Update MongoDB date field using value of another date field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with the following instance:

`{ id: 1, createdAt: ISODate("2018-12-25T21:18:06.791+0000") }`

And I would like to use an update operation for adding another date field that take its value from the `createdAt` field:

`{ id: 1, createdAt: ISODate("2018-12-25T21:18:06.791+0000"), newField: ISODate("2018-12-25T21:18:06.791+0000") }`

Is there a possible way of doing so? I tried this code right here:

```
collection.updateMany({
    {},
    $set: {
        newField: '$createdAt'
    }
});
```

But it failed to generate my desire result.
Thanks!

(Mongodb version 4.0.2)

Comment: Please show us your full command, not just the set operation.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can use the aggregation pipeline for update operations. In this case, you can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#addfields-aggregation):

```
db.collection.update(
  {filer},
  [{
    $addFields: {
      newField: '$createdAt'
    }
  }]
)
```

Comment: @dneumark, why not upgrading to latest version of MongoDB?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit dev ops issues :/